# Multiple fires of hover not solved using .stop() or .stop(true,true)

Tags: jquery, hover

Here I have an example of a jQuery flip effect: http://jsfiddle.net/JfUbW/112/

The problem I think is because I'm making the width of the front image go to 0, so when at the edge of the image, it causes the hover to fire over and over as the front image moves out from under the mouse and so long as the mouse is moving at that time it inadvertently fires hover again on the the below image.

I've tried to use .stop() and .stop(true,true) but that actually seems to make the problem worse.

Any ideas?

```
$(window).load(function() {
image_width = $(".front").width();
margin = image_width / 2 + 'px';
image_width += 'px';

compress = {
    width: 0,
    marginLeft: margin,
    opacity: 0
};
decompress = {
    width: image_width,
    marginLeft: 0,
    opacity: 1
}

$(".back").css(compress); 
$('.front').parent().hover(function() {
        $('.front').delay(150).animate(compress, 100);
        $('.back').delay(150).animate(decompress, 100);
    }, 
    function() {
        $('.back').delay(150).animate(compress, 100);
        $('.front').delay(150).animate(decompress, 100);
    }

);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flip on hover and "flop" on out, you can have the `.container` div keeps its size.

Add the following CSS:

```css
.container{
    width: 180px;
    height:180px;
}
```

or set its size programmatically either at event attachment or execution.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/JfUbW/115/).